# Unable to create project in vscode terminal

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]

I'm new to Flutter and was trying to create a flutter project in the vscode terminal, but it tells me that there are "Multiple output directories specified". How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove spaces from your project name
(flutter create my_application)
Instead of space put this _

Answer (score 0):

```
 flutter create --org <Package name> <Project Name>
```

Empty project :-

```
 flutter create <Project Name>
```