# Multiple output directories specified error

Tags: flutter, syntax-error

Hey i am new i am working on a tutorial how can i solve this.

I am making a grocery application project, And I don't know that much about coding, just entered.

Can someone solve it and give it and what is the problem, can anyone tell?

Comment: Hi! Welcome :) In its current state, your question is not really answerable as we don't have any surrounding context about your problem. I recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to format a question to help us help you better! Once you've had a read, come back and edit your question to try and improve it (or if its been closed by then, ask a new question)

Comment: However in this particular case, it may just be that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077673/9063935) previous answer solves your problem. If it does solve your problem then that's great :) but next time you ask a question, make sure you've done all the research you can, and then presented your research and problem specifically in the question (along with all the other tips in the link above!). Good luck!

Comment: Please be more specific. Before diving into Flutter at least try to improve your coding skills first. You can start with a fundamental programming language like C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.